# Override Default Dataform Submission JS Activity In Magento

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs

For my instance, I would like to override the default actions including validation whenever a customer modifies their address. Server side is taken care of, but I would like to hook into the form submission method I believe to be within varien/form.js so that I can trigger my own validation, popups, etc.

Note that I already know how to add the js in only the appropriate place via layout update:

```
<customer_address_form>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>addressverification.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</customer_address_form>
```

And I know that I can use the built in validation classes (i dont want to)

How can I override the default method?

How would you trace to that method with firebug or cdt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Validation.prototype.onSubmit = Validation.prototype.onSubmit.wrap(function(parentMethod,ev){
    parentMethod(ev);
    return false;
});
```